# Possible ambiguity in function of に

Tags: grammar, particle-に

> 日本人**にも**人気のリゾート地として知られるフィリピンのボラカイ島で...
>   On the Phillipine island of Borakai, which is known as a resort popular even with Japanese people, ...

I can't decide if this にも goes with 人気, so that it's "a resort popular **even with** Japanese people", or whether it goes with 知られる so that it's "a popular resort known **even by** Japanese people".

Is one of these options obviously wrong? Or is the sentence a little ambiguous?
If I had to choose I'd go with my first option simply because にも is right next to 人気.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sentence is a little ambiguous and can be interpreted as having both meanings.

However I interpret it as "a popular resort known even by Japanese people". Because, if it means "a resort popular even with Japanese people", it should be 日本人にも人気の、リゾート地として知られるフィリピンのボラカイ島 or 日本人にも人気があり、リゾート地として知られるフィリピンのボラカイ島.